# Use Gulp To Copy File Into Directory Named After Filename

Tags: gulp

I have the following files

```
assets
---views
------pages
---------some_page.ejs
---------another_page.ejs
```

When I build these ejs files, I want them to go into the following file structure

```
public
---some_page
------index.html
---another_page
------index.html
```

My gulp file contains the following build command:

```
gulp.task('build-html', function() {
return gulp.src('assets/views/pages/*.ejs')
    .pipe(ejs())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/???')); // WHAT DO I ADD HERE TO MAKE ABOVE WORK?
});
```

I'm totally stumped what I need to add into the gulp.dest function to achieve the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `gulp-rename` package:

```
gulp.task('build-html', function() {
return gulp.src('assets/views/pages/*.ejs')
    .pipe(ejs())
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
       path.dirname += "/" + path.basename;
       path.basename = "index";
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
});
```